# Separating Axis Theorem for Obstacle Detection

Tags: python, algorithm, simulation, path-finding, robotics

I'm currently working on a Robotics project. The project objective is to create a nonholonomic robot path finding algorithm to be integrated into an actual STM Controller. I am currently stuck at solving the obstacle detection part using the separating axis theorem.

```
 def has_collided(self, obj_1: List, obj_2: List):
        polygons = [obj_1, obj_2]
        for polygon in polygons:
            for i1 in range(len(polygon)):
                i2 = (i1 + 1) % len(polygon)
                p1 = polygon[i1]
                p2 = polygon[i2]

                normal = [p2[1] - p1[1], p1[0] - p2[0]]

                min_1, max_1 = self.check_projection(normal, obj_1)
                min_2, max_2 = self.check_projection(normal, obj_2)
                if max_1 < min_2 or max_2 < min_1:
                    return False
        return True

def check_projection(self, normal, points):
    min_val, max_val = None, None
    for point in points:
        projected = normal[0] * point[0] + normal[1] * point[1]
        if min_val is None or projected < min_val:
            min_val = projected
        if max_val is None or projected > max_val:
            max_val = projected

    return min_val, max_val
```

Also in my main function, this is how function implements the obstacle detection.

```
collided = 0
for obs in self.obstacles:
    if self.robot.has_collided(self.robot.get_robot_corners(neighbour_x_cts, neighbour_y_cts,
                                                math.radians(neighbour_theta_cts)), obs):
       collided = 1
       print("collided")
       break
 if collided:
    continue
```

The process currently takes very long to search for a path (always never finding one) when I activate the above code in the main.py to enable the obstacle detection.

Would appreciate some guidance on this :) Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you edit the question with what `check_projection` looks like? The base function looks correct.

Comment: Make sure your polygons are convex and have no zero-length edges.

Comment: You can get some inspiration here. https://cs.au.dk/~gerth/advising/thesis/lukas-walther.pdf Detecting intersection of two convex polygons can be done in truly short time.

Comment: @BTables Hi I have edited the question and included the implementation of the obstacle detection part in the main.py as well.

Comment: You're not actually calling `has_collided` anywhere. But, assuming you are somewhere else I believe it has to be an issue with your input data; your SAT implementation is correct. It's most likely bad pre-processing on the data, I would check the polygons/robot bounding box manually.

Comment: @BTables Sorry I just edited the code to the correct one. Currently the algorithm iterates over 17000 paths before finding a path to goal, it's because of the processing of input data? Any advice on how I can improve the searching algorithm? I'm implementing this on a hybrid a* algorithm. Thank you for your help

Comment: @awkwardsquid122 path planning and collision detection are two separate problems. A* should already factor in occupied spaces within something like a cost map. If you're using SAT for collision detection that should be done dynamically only on a local path you're actively navigating.

Comment: @BTables Does that mean I shouldn't use SAT for detecting the obstacles in A*?

Comment: Not while actively searching for a path. The graph you feed into A* should already know about what's a valid path.